# how to use sba(sparse bundle adjustment)

Tags: c++, computer-vision

I want to use sba to do bundle adjustment task, and I would like to use sba-1.6(http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/sba/). But the user manual do not tell exactly how to use it. and I am kind of confused.
For example, I want to use this function sba_mot_levmar which has a parameter p I do not understand what it is. The problem here is that the provided examples make the rotation part in p to be 0. so that is p? 
and after call this function, what is in p?

```
int sba_mot_levmar(
const int n,   /* number of points */
const int m,   /* number of images */
const int mcon,
char *vmask,  
double *p,    /* initial parameter vector p0: (a1, ..., am).
               * aj are the image j parameters, size m*cnp */
const int cnp,/* number of parameters for ONE camera; e.g. 6 for Euclidean cameras */
double *x,    
double *covx, 
const int mnp,
void (*proj)(int j, int i, double *aj, double *xij, void *adata),

void (*projac)(int j, int i, double *aj, double *Aij, void *adata),

void *adata,      

const int itmax,   
const double opts[SBA_OPTSSZ]
double info[SBA_INFOSZ]
)
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem. Did you find out a solution?

Comment: you can read source code, and you will find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's good tutorials for how to use **sba** with **Ros**, yet I am not sure if it is Lourakis implementation :

-http://wiki.ros.org/sba/Tutorials/IntroductionToSBA

it explain an example, and lately I found a wrapper for it in python (if you don't care about the language used):

-https://pypi.org/project/sba/

I believe these are easier to use and run than the straight-forward way you mention